# Firewalld how to allow connections on a port to all ips?

Tags: postgresql, centos, firewalld

I'm trying to configure firewalld on my VPS server and I'm trying to open a port for my postgresql server.

So far, I have done the following:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --new-zone=postgresqlrule --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=postgresqlrule --add-port=5432/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

How do I use `--add-source` to add a wildcard for all ips?

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=postgresqlrule --add-source= *
```

The above returns the following error:

```
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-sfo3-01 ~]# sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=postgresqlrule --add-source= *
usage: see firewall-cmd man page
firewall-cmd: error: unrecognized arguments: mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch.rpm steam-game-scraper
```

I basically have to give some classmates access to this database, but I don't want to have to find out each of their IPs. I couldn't find anything related to opening connections to all IPs online.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **pg_hba.conf** file in this location (*/etc/postgresql/12/main*) and add the following line at the end:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

It allows access to all databases for all users.

Restart Postgresql by writing this command `service postgresql restart`

Comment: I already have that entry in my pg_hba.conf file which worked until I enabled `firewalld`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I added my public IP to a different zone so it was already tied to that zone thus refusing connections to anything else.

I removed that source IP, and it's now accepting connections on that port.